# Android - Google Analytics. Tracking activity views

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to count the number of activity views in my application.
The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide) says that I may call `tracker.startNewSession();` method directly in the `onCreate()` method of my Activity if my application has only one Activity. And then below says:

> If you have multiple Activities in your application, you **can** use
>   the EasyTracker Library

I have multiple activities in my application, but I don't want to use EasyTracker.

My question is, should I call `tracker.startNewSession();` for every activity, or only for once? let say in a splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some investigations it turned out that EasyTracker was more suitable for my case, so I ended up using it.